# How to run the same test with multiple logins, URL's, and body elements in cypress.io

Tags: cypress

I have a simple test I want to create in cypress that would require a test where using a settings file I would create 1 test that executes for each entry in the settings file.  The file would contain user/pwd/url/elementID and be used to login for each user at a custom  URL, and  validate that a specific elementID is displayed, logout, and do it again - iterating through the settings file until each is tested.

I want to do something like:

```
forEach(URL,uname,pwd,elementID) do
     cy.request(URL)
     cy.get('input:uname').btn.click
     cy.get('input:pwd').btn.click
     cy.get(data-cy=elementID).should(be present)
     cy.get(btn.logout).btn.click
```

I highly doubt the above code is correct - but hopefully you get the idea.  Main goal is to create a simple and quick script that will quickly iterate through an array to smoke test the functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still iterate over your test data and create a test case out of each:

```js
[
    {
        url,
        uname,
        pwd,
        elementID,
    }
].forEach(testData => {
    it(`Test ${testData.uname} on ${testData.url}`, () => {
        // your test code
    });
});
```

Of course the array:

```
[
    {
        url,
        uname,
        pwd,
        elementID,
    }
]
```

does not need to be there in the same file, you can have it somewhere separate and import it into your spec file.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. In case you have URLs of different origin, you need to test them all in a seperate "it" instance.

Comment: An example of importing the data from a fixture file is given [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests/cypress/integration/fixture-spec.js)

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:** You can only visit URLs from the same origin in one test! This code will only work if all URLs you want to test are from the same origin (i.e. same

Save your data in json format and put them in Cypress folder "fixtures"

```json
[
{"user":"username1","pwd":"pwuser1","url":"url1","elementID":"#element_name1"},
{"user":"username2","pwd":"pwuser2","url":"url2","elementID":"#element_name2"}
]
```

(Don't forget the # in front of the element_name id)

Then this is your smoke_test.spec.js

```js
//fetch the parameters from the file and save them as constant "login"

const login_data = require('../fixtures/login_data.json')

//Now you can fetch the parameters using "login_data"

describe('smoke test', () => {
    it('loop through login list', () => {
        //we call each entry "param" and loop through the lines of the json file
        cy.get(login_data).each((param) => {
            cy.visit(param.url)
            cy.get('#id_of_username_field').type(param.user)
            cy.get('#id_of_pw_field').type(param.pwd)
            //The next line is only if you have a login button
            cy.get('#id_of_login_button').click()

            cy.get(param.elementID).should('be.visible')
            cy.get('#id_of_logout_button)
        })
    })
})
```